# angular 10 - how to use RouterModule

Tags: angular

I'm trying to add to one of my components a button that will redirect the page to a different component :

```
<input type="button" value="Shops List" [routerLink]="['shops-list']" class="btn">
```

In the module (child) of that component I configured the following import :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ... ],
  exports: [ ... ],
  imports: [ ....,RouterModule.forChild([{ path: 'shops-list', component: ShopListComponent}])] ,
  providers: [ ..., Router],
})
export class ProductModule{ }
```

I'm not sure what to import in my AppModule ? I tried to import only RouterModule but I got an error in my console :

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[RouterModule -> Router -> Function -> Function -> Function]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Function!
```

I tried also to add the same route path only for RouterModule.forRoot :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [........,
    RouterModule.forRoot([{ path: 'shops-list', component: ShopListComponent}])],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

but then my button didn`t redirect to the ShopListComponent.

I read multiple posts and docs about the difference between them (forChild,forRoot) but it still isnt clear to me. I understood that we want to avoid having 2 instances of RouterModule in each module and our goal is to create the router instance in  the main component and inject it in children.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm new to angular.. trying to learn by doing and not just reading

Comment: Good that try learn doc about and try, it is highly recommended

Comment: I read those docs, they are very different from all the examples I saw in the posts here. The docs talk about creating a dedicated routing module while in all the examples I saw we create the instance of the routerModule in the AppModule

Comment: Ok I show You in my answer one simple example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normaly all route You need define like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: StatechoisComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'top'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

from here navigate to some componet use  somethig like this:

```
<button mat-button routerLink='/login'>
```

Import components to You RouteModules

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { StatechoisComponent } from './statechois/statechois.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
```

This is screen from my project, is example for show how is work
[image: code]

and this is result, if You compare my code in RouterModule try understand why You see two same elements
[image]

Comment: and I just need to import this module in my AppModule and thats all ?

Comment: Does it matters in what module the component that has the button is located ?

Comment: Normaly if You create project need answer some question, among others about Routing, if You clic yes only what You need to do is import component to You RouteModule and set link like in my answer

Comment: I have 3 modules : A,B,AppModule. Module A needs to redirect the page to Module B via this button. I done everything u mentioned, the redirection changes the url but the Components inside ModuleB arent loaded

Comment: In app.component.html You need add this <router-outlet></router-outlet> this decorator o something else where change what component You see.

Comment: Done that, it really redirected my page to the other component. However, in the reloaded page, I have the component from module A on top of the component of Module B. My app.html has now the tag that u mentioned and a tag for a component from model B that has that button

Comment: Thanks for the help ! The reason I had  this issue is because in my app.component.html I used a component from Module B and the router-outlet. I had to clean the app.component.html and leave only the router-outlete and configure the default page not in the app.component.html but rather in the routing module under path ' '.  Thanks again !